# Rails: Simpleform inside of table input type = text_area- how to set its height?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, html-table, simple-form

I'm using the "Simpleform" gem for my rails app and I have a form embedded in a table.

One of the elements of the form is a text_area. However, the entire row of the table is very tall because of this input type. I would like to set its height so that the rows are not so tall.

How do I do that I tried the following but that didn't seem to change anything

```
 <% @listings.each do |listing| %>  
<%= simple_form_for(listing, :html => {:multipart => true, :class=> '.form-inline'} ) do |f| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= listing.id %></td>
    <td><%= listing.name %></td>
    <td><%= f.input :telephone %></td>
    <td><%= f.input :fax %></td>
    <td><%= f.input :suite %></td>

    <td> <%= f.input :notes, :size => 5 %></td>
        <td> <%= f.button :submit %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried CSS, find the form id and apply your desired height to the textarea propert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
<td> <%= f.input :notes, :input_html => { :rows => 5 } %></td>
```

The input_html option will add arbitrary attributes to the resulting HTML tag.  In the case of a textarea, there is no 'size' attribute, only 'cols' or 'rows'.

I haven't tested this myself, but I've used :input_html for other HTML attributes.  Let me know how you fare!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code Ben submitted:

```
<td> <%= f.input :notes, :input_html => { :rows => 5 } %></td>
```

But, it might be a better idea to use the helper classes simple form uses. From memory, and with your custom class, something like this should work:

```
.form-inline .text{
  height: 300px;
}
```

This keeps styling separate in your css, as it should be.